# Unable to view execution of RobotFramework tests when using Selenium2Library and Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, robotframework

I'm using Jenkins to run RobotFramework test suites on a Windows 7 machine. The setup I am using is nearly identical to the one described on this: http://eficode.fi/en/blog/setting-up-a-continuous-integration-system/ site, save the differing O/S. Essentially, I am using Jenkins with the robotframework plugin, and am using a multi-configuration project to run my tests in multiple browsers at once (chrome and firefox).

Overall, testing works as expected: the test suites run and generate the appropriate log files. The problem is that the browsers are *hidden* during the run. I can see the webdrivers running in Task Manager, and I can watch the console output become written in Jenkins, but am unable to see the test executing onscreen. Though, if I run my tests directly from command line the browsers display themselves as expected.

Any ideas how I can force the browsers to display when run using Jenkins?

Comment: Are you using selenium grid? If so, have you tried opening a remote session (ms remote desktop, vnc, etc) to the machines running the grid?

Comment: I am using Selenium2Library. I am not running selenium grid or selenium server myself, though maybe selenium2library runs them automatically? 

I have the Jenkins project configured to an SVN repo, though it says it's running locally (C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Robot Framework\workspace). When builds are running, I can see chromedriver.exe and firefox.exe in the task manager (UserName:SYSTEM), and these tasks end when the builds end. So I don't think that I need to remote into anything (though I could be wrong).

(btw, The Robot Framework hub is awesome! Thanks!)

Comment: I found the issue. I had Jenkins running as a background process, meaning it couldn't display GUIs. A more complete response can be found here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24842837/browser-never-opens-when-running-robot-framework-tests-from-jenkins)